# How to acess Slote value in my Lambda function for an alexa skill?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make an alexa skill that checks if the slot value informed exists in an external API. This functionality will serve as an authentication.

Until now, this is what I have:

```
class VerificarCpfIntent(AbstractRequestHandler):
"""Handler for Verificar CPF Intent."""
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
    return is_intent_name("VerificarCpfIntent")(handler_input)

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
    cpf = slots['cpf']
    if cpf.value:
        response = requests.get(the-externallAPI).json()

        cpfs_cnpjs = []
        for msg in response['Data']:
            for cpf_cnpj in msg['ConsumidorObj'].get('CpfsCnpjs', []):
                cpfs_cnpjs.append(cpf_cnpj[1])
            cpfs_cnpjs = list(dict.fromkeys(cpfs_cnpjs))

        if cpf in cpfs_cnpjs:
            speech_text = "Olá fulano"
        else:
            speech_text = "Humm, não encontrei seu usuário, se você não possuir login no aplicativo ou plataforma, crie um usuário em um desses canais"
    else:
        speech_text = "Ok"

    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speech_text).set_should_end_session(True)
            .response
    )
```

When I try to make a call to perform the authentication, this are my logs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31pX5.png)

And this is the JSON returned:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5sE2.png)

```
"request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.1a39351f-719e-4755-84b6-7b5a65c2e03e",
    "locale": "pt-BR",
    "timestamp": "2021-11-12T11:16:22Z",
    "intent": {
        "name": "VerificarCpfIntent",
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "slots": {
            "cpf": {
                "name": "cpf",
                "value": "555",
                "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                "source": "USER",
                "slotValue": {
                    "type": "Simple",
                    "value": "555"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I dont't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm a Python beginner.

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. What's not working? Where are you stuck? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I'm not getting the resulting in the if section that performs the search throught the CPFs.

Comment: The only response im getting is the "else: print("Ok").

Comment: In log there is no error or such a thing. I guess is the logic of rhe code!

Comment: You could try to add some logging output to your function by using `print()`.  You could add `print("CPF:", cpf)` before your `if cpf.value` to see if you get the value you're expeccting